# How can I view a different Action in the 3d viewport?

Tags: animation, actions

I made a model with two actions: Idle and Walk. I exported it and both animations worked great. When I re-opened the file today, the Walk action is the only one that will play. It's almost like the Idle action was overwritten by the Walk action, although I can see that is not the case by inspecting the dots in the Action Editor window.

It's weird, even if I select the Idle action, then delete all keyframes, the Action selector switches to say "+ New" and pressing spacebar or scrubbing the timeline *still shows the Walk action*! I can't figure out how to visually display another action, and thereby actually be able to work on another action.

I have tried searching on Google and this site for help but I am not sure how to phrase it.

Comment: I was messing around with this for hours today and wouldn't you know it, it suddenly just started working as soon as I posted this. I think the thing that made it work was by specifically selecting the skeleton and then going into Pose mode, and now suddenly it all functions again.

Comment: have you pushed your action into the Nonlinear Animation Editor? In that case it will play even though you don't see it in the Dope Sheet anymore. But maybe share your armature here: https://pasteall.org/blend/